# How Collection.sort in is implemented?

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

I'm using  `Collection.sort(Array<objectX>, Comperator<objectX>)` in java/Android.

In my comperator I compare two objects using their ID.

How can I know in which method this sort is made? (quicksort, mergesort...)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732522/how-do-you-compare-2-items-in-a-generic-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking which algorithm to use is not specified (in other words it's runtime library specific).

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

> For example, the algorithm used by `sort` does not have to be a mergesort, but it does have to be *stable*.

In practice, it typically chooses one sorting technique of of several based on the length of the list etc. In the standard implementation from Sun/Oracle it chooses between insertion sort (if the length is less than 7) and merge sort otherwise.

Comment: As of Java 7, it uses something more awesome (albeit much more complicated) called TimSort.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the code if you want:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java